# SQL Server Service takes many retries to start after a reboot but eventually starts

Tags: sql-server

My local Windows Service "SQL Server", which is a 2016 installation, is failing. However, if i retry, many, many times (like 30 times), or perhaps if I just wait long enough after a reboot, it does eventually start. This makes me think that not all dependent services (?) have been fully loaded at the time that I try to start it and that if I wait for some dependency to eventually start, the SQL Service service will also start. However, it seems to take a really long time.

I'd like to try and identify what dependency needs to be started first and mark sure that I do not have 'delayed start" as the start up mode for it, However, I have not been able to identify which service-if any-needs to be running for the SQL Server service to start.

i see the following errors in the event log. Do these help suggest what t he underlying issue is?

```
The Open Procedure for service "WmiApRpl" in DLL "C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wmiaprpl.dll" failed. Performance data for this service will not be available. The first four bytes (DWORD) of the Data section contains the error code.


SQL Server is terminating because of fatal exception c0000005. This error may be caused by an unhandled Win32 or C++ exception, or by an access violation encountered during exception handling. Check the SQL error log for any related stack dumps or messages. This exception forces SQL Server to shutdown. To recover from this error, restart the server (unless SQLAgent is configured to auto restart).
```

Comment: SQL Server has no dependent services. The error you quote seems irrelevant. What does SQL Server's own ERRORLOG say just prior to the `c0000005` (which is an access violation)? This could be anything from a hardware problem to an overzealous anti-virus.

Comment: you could try to start sql server from the console and see any kind of errors or output more clearly.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem. Any memory parity errors or hard disk timeout/retry failures in the system event logs?